grafana tracing visualization as "Traces" shows nothing
I've configured an x-ray datasourceinto my grafana.
I'm trying to visualize typical stacked span visualization.
In order to get it, I'm trying to set visualization type to "Traces", but it's showing me nothing.
However, when I set visualization type to "Table", I'm getting raw data shown:

I'd like to get visualization span as:

